# Кодировка UTF-8, UTF-16. Как правильно работать с Unicode?

Tags: java, unicode

Хочу вывести букву [Ư Latin Capital Letter U with Horn](https://unicode-table.com/en/01AF/)  - получаю знаки вопроса. Вывожу как `System.out.println('\uC6AF');`. Пробовал и `UTF-8` и `UTF-16` и с помощью `chcp` - ничего не помогает. Как правильно работать с Unicode?

Comment: Смотря куда вы выводите - то ли на браузер, то ли на консоль или еще куда то. Все зависит от кодировки которую поддерживает/не поддерживает устройство вывода

Comment: @Barmaley вывод в консоль и в файл тоже пробовал записывать

Comment: Проблема с файлом ровно такая же как и с консолью - чтобы увидеть, что записано в файле, вам надо открыть его каким-то вьюером, который может поддерживать, а может и не поддерживать UTF-8/16 - так что сути это не меняет. Скорее всего в вашем случае консоль не поддерживает кодировку. Попробуйте [EditPad](https://www.editpadpro.com/unicode.html) вручную выставьте там кодировку текста и посмотрите то не то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внимательнее читайте свою же ссылку: [Ư Latin Capital Letter U with Horn](https://unicode-table.com/en/01AF/). Там написано:

```
Unicode number U+01AF
```

то есть в `Java` надо написать:

```
System.out.println('\u01AF');
```

---

Чтобы выводилось в правильной кодировке - установите кодировку проекта `UTF-8` в IDE.

В IDEA это делается так: [Settings ⇒ Editor ⇒ File Encodings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB5X5.png).

**Примечание:** Если есть проблема с кодировкой самой консоли, выводить можно в файл.

---

Полностью код выглядит так:

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // "ISO-8859-1" - западноевропейские языки
        // "windows-1251" - стандартная Windows (русская)
        // "UTF-8" - юникод
        String systemEncoding = "UTF-8";

        String text =
                '\u01AF' + " - Latin Capital Letter U with Horn\r\n" +
                '\u0168' + " - Latin Capital Letter U with Tilde\r\n" +
                '\u0055' + " - Latin Capital Letter U\r\n";

        // вывод в консоль
        System.out.printf(text, systemEncoding);

        // вывод в файл
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =
                new FileOutputStream("types_of_u_letters.txt", false);
        fileOutputStream.write(text.getBytes(systemEncoding));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего потому, что буква 'U' имеет кодировку 0055.
Смотрите актуальную версию таблицы юникод, например здесь:
https://unicode-table.com/ru/#control-character
Соответственно, вывод этой буквы через юникод будет такой:
System.out.println("\u0055");